# Azure Ad authentication not working for new asp.net core 2.1 with angular 5.2 new template. Since we do not route to home controller in new template

Tags: c#, jquery, angular, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.1

We have migrated our .net core 2.1 with angular 4.3 to .net core 2.1 with angular 5.2.

Now we are not able to do azure ad authentication from startup.cs as there is change in MapRoute defination. For refrence,

Previous:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
```

latest:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
```

Previously we used to navigate to home controller and index.cshtml after authentication. But now there is no .cshtml in new template.

Comment: Hi vikas ! I'm also facing the same problem migrating my app to this new project template where there is no more cshtml file...Did you solve your problem ?

Comment: Yes i have solved the problem. What problem you are facing?

Comment: I posted my solution. Did you use the same method ?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the exact same problem migrating my app from angular 5/.Net Core 2.0 to angular 7/.Net Core 2.2 and i found a way to keep the authentication server side.
The solution for that is to add a middleware that check if every request is authenticated and if it's not the case, force it.

```
        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                await context.ChallengeAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                await next();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because of the reply URL.

When authentication is performed, user is redirected to the reply URL. 
This URL is configured in AAD.

You may have configured the root URL of application in reply URL which does not contain any controller or action.   That's why application is not able to route request to anywhere.

You can verify this in Azure Portal.

**EDIT:**
Based on your comment, i would suggest to check if you have used "UseDefaultFiles".

UseDefaultFiles tries to find a page with name "Default" or "Index". But if page with these names are not available, then you need to write custom logic.

Let's say you want to make "mydefault.html" as default document then the logic would be as below.

Refer [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-2.2#serve-a-default-document).

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    // Serve my app-specific default file, if present.
    DefaultFilesOptions options = new DefaultFilesOptions();
    options.DefaultFileNames.Clear();
    options.DefaultFileNames.Add("mydefault.html");
    app.UseDefaultFiles(options);
    app.UseStaticFiles();
}
```

Comment: Actually it is not going to the Microsoft login page as the new template has been changed. Previously we use to have index.cshtml. But now there is no view available in new templates. I think as per new template we need to write authentication on client side only. Waiting for your reply

Comment: I hope you have used app.UseDefaultFiles() in the startup configure method.  This method looks for page with name "Default" or "Index" if no page is specified.  But if you dont have pages with these names then you need to tell this method which should be default page.  Edited my original answer to provide answer.

Comment: Thank you manoj for reply. But the issue is authenticating to https://login.microsoftonline.com/ in startup.cs file. Previously it was working with home controller and index.cdshtml. But now the new template does not have view folder. instead of which we haves pages folder.

Comment: can you check in fiddler on what is happening ?  You can check request is failing to reach your web server OR it is failing when trying to reach Azure AD url (login.microsoftonline.com).  That would help you to confirm the exact issue.